# Rendering before MUI Slide transition effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, transition

I have this react component (i know its not great - improvement suggestions also welcome),  issue i have to focus on is that the render of `formElements` happens, then the transition effect takes place for `Slide`, so there is a flash of the component then the transition effect.

How do i prevent / delay the render of the `formElements` so that the transition happens before the render.

I have tried onEntered - setting showInputArea as true, onEntering - showInputArea as false, but that seems to stick at false and not trigger the callback to set true / show `formElements`, and removing the timeout, but that removes the transition effect or does not set as true to show elements.

```
import { Container, Slide } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { FormElement } from '..';
import { shouldAutoAdvance } from '../Page/page.helpers';

const InputArea = ({
  components,
  currentPage,
  formInputsParentRef,
  iFrameId,
  pageComponentIds,
  slideDirection,
  visiblePageComponents,
}) => {
  // When the app is first loaded we should show the inputArea with no transition.
  const isFirstLoad = slideDirection === undefined;
  const [showInputArea, setShowInputArea] = useState(isFirstLoad);
  useEffect(() => {
    // When a user navigates through the form we trigger a slide transition by briefly hiding
    // then showing the inputArea thereby triggering the transition.
    setShowInputArea(isFirstLoad);
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (slideDirection !== undefined) {
        setShowInputArea(true);
      }
    }, 0.1);
  }, [currentPage]);
  const formElements = pageComponentIds.map((componentId) => {
    const elementData = components[`component_${componentId}`];
    const { component, input } = elementData;
    const { type, duration, text, mappedQuestionId } = component;

    return (
      // TODO here we are passing all the data we need down, but in some components we are also selecting from the store - investigate if / how we can and try to improve this
      <FormElement
        autoAdvance={shouldAutoAdvance(elementData, visiblePageComponents)}
        componentId={componentId}
        currentPage={currentPage}
        duration={duration}
        iFrameId={iFrameId}
        isVisible={visiblePageComponents.includes(elementData)}
        key={componentId}
        mappedQuestionId={mappedQuestionId}
        slideDirection={slideDirection}
        text={text}
        type={type}
        value={input?.value}
      />
    );
  });

  return (
    <Slide
      direction={slideDirection}
      in={showInputArea}
      exit={false}
      appear={false}
      timeout={500}
    >
      <Container ref={formInputsParentRef} maxWidth="md">
        {formElements}
      </Container>
    </Slide>
  );
};

export default InputArea;
```